# Мой код не запускается в IntellijIDE

Tags: java

Я только начал изучать java. Когда напишу код в IntellijIDE , код не запускается.  [Отображается ещё одна окна.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTa8t.jpg)

Comment: 1. У вас на скриншоте Android Studio. 2. Какой код? Добавьте его пожалуйста в вопрос (для этого нажмите на кнопку `Править`)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй создать новый проект. Левый верхний угол File-new-project. Там выбираешь название, расположение, Язык-java, build system-intelliJ. И create. Чтобы запустить код ищешь зеленую кнопку play.

А вообще советую видосы по установке и настройке глянуть:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lzvnYTClYg